# Foreign key is being updated as null

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to implement a bi-directional relationship using @OneToMany and @ManyToOne JPA annotation. My foreign key is being updated as NULL which is not correct. I need some input to resolve this.

I have created User and CardInfo class. I am trying to add a relationship where User can have more than one card. When I am trying to persist in database foreign key is being inserted as null.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_info")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    //@GeneratedValue
    private String userId;
    private String userName;
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    private boolean primeMember;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<CardInfo> paymentDetails;
```

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="card_info")
public class CardInfo implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String cardNumber;
    @Id
    private String cardType; // Debit, Credit
    private String cardCategory; // Visa, mastercard
    private Date expiryDate;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include private User user;
```

```
public class DAOImpl {
@Transactional
    public String addCustomer(User user) {
//        User _user=new User();
//        Set<CardInfo> cardData=new HashSet<>();
//
        String userId=String.valueOf(Instant.now().toEpochMilli());
        user.setUserId(userId);
Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.persist(user);
return userId;
}
```

```
mysql> select * from card_info;
+----------+-------------+--------------+---------------------+---------+
| cardType | cardNumber  | cardCategory | expiryDate          | user_id |
+----------+-------------+--------------+---------------------+---------+
| CREDIT   | 74959454959 | VISA         | 2020-04-23 00:00:00 | NULL    |
+----------+-------------+--------------+---------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

user_id column should not be updated as NULL. Please correct me if understanding is not correct.

Comment: Where are you persisting `CardInfo`? Are you properly associating a `User` to it before persisting?

Comment: User object has cardInfo object and also I used CascadeType.PERSIST, then I do not need to persist CardInfo explicitly. I am simply generating userId which I am associating in DAO.Impl class.

Comment: You are adding a new `CardDetail` to a `User`, but is the `User` set in the `CardDetail`? If not, can you try it?

Comment: CardDetail was not set in User. This is the root cause my "user_id" field was set as NULL. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `Cascade.PERSIST` ensures that `CardInfo` objects will be persist together with their parent `User`, it is the responsibility of the application, or the object model to maintain relationships<sup>[[[1](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany)]](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany)</sup>.

As the foreign key is in `CardInfo`, you have to ensure that every `CardInfo` is associated to the `User` that you are persisting. A common pattern is to add extra logic to handle both sides of the relationship in the domain object, e.g.:

```
public class User {

    // fields, accessors and mutators

    public void addPaymentDetails(CardInfo cardInfo) {
        if (paymentDetails == null) {
            paymentDetails = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        }
        if (cardInfo.getUser() != this) {
            cardInfo.setUser(this);
        }
        paymentDetails.add(cardInfo);
    }

}
```

The above code ensures that both sides of the relationship are in sync (i.e., if a user adds a card to its paymental details, then the card info is "owned" by the user).

Finally, while not directly related to your problem, my advice would be to make the relationship between `CardInfo` and `User` mandatory and its respective join column `NOT NULL` so that queries are properly optimised and no `CardInfo` can exist in the database without an association to its owning `User`:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable = false)
```